# Rails how to change url for seo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

i am coding a news website. I'm trying to implement best seo practices. 
For seo , post urls should be like :  ( i use friendlyId gem )

```
www.mywebsite.com/blog-post-title
```

But if i use rails style , it generates this url for me:

```
www.mywebsite.com/post/blog-post-title
```

i tried to override routes like :

```
resources :post #, :path => "/"
```

But when i do this , posts work well but i can't access my other routes like :

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact  www.mywebsite.com/admin
```

in this way , rails see all pages as post.

I need help to do this !

Comment: Could you post whole `routes.rb`, please?  And try to put `resources :post #, :path => "/"` in the end of `routes.rb`. It should work

Comment: Have a look at https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1209730

Comment: thanks Nikita. Very reasonable ! it works now. I have lots of routes above but this way does not effect my other routes.

Comment: @YalınSemer great. I'll post an answer then so you could chose the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put `resources :post #, :path => "/"` in the end of `routes.rb`. It should work